Starting from a DEM raster, is it possible to arrive at a polygonal layer with a slope greater than 30% not in squares?
On this site it is possible to download DEM maps of Italy with an accuracy of 10 meters: https://tinitaly.pi.ingv.it/Download_Area1_1.html
Bringing this raster into QGIS and running the Slope command achieves this:

Then with "reclassify by table" I create my percentage cases and then using "polygonize (raster to vetor) I reach this:

The output polygonal vector is squared.
Is it possible to have it not squared? Maybe creating a lattice as "contour lines" and then creating the vector file?

Dissolve the resulting polygons based on the bins you picked.  These values should be in the attribute table of the polygons.

Did you see https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/193233/convert-raster-to-smooth-contour-polygons-in-qgis?  You might try the v.generalize tools (there are several methods with different parameters) or the SAGA smooth tool.  If you are just concerned with looks you could use the geometry generator to smooth things, or you could have smoothed the raster prior to polygonizing perhaps with a SAGA Gaussian filter.
